# how to store sql query results in a variable in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

query i am using

string query = "select rescod from tbres,tbmnu where rescod = mnures and mnucod =1";

result from this query is 5

i would like to store the result of this query in an integer variable RESULT

Comment: Have you spent any time doing any basic research? I think you should find an ado.net or entity framework tutorial (depending which of those you are using to interact with your database). You will find answers to this kind of general question, and much more. (hint: in the case of ado.net you may want to look into the executeScalar method)

Answer (score 2):

### This could be the answer you're looking for.

```
string connectionstring = //your connectionstring    

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
     conn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(/*Your query here between quotation marks*/, conn);
     int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     conn.Close();
}
```

Be sure to look into sql because this is some basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You should use, Ado dot Net (You can find so many tutorial). Simple use Ado . Net

1. First Create Connection String
2. Open the Connection
3. Select command (Query)
4. Store or Read he result via EcecuteScaler(For Single Result) Datareader or Dataset or Datatable (For More than Single Result)

Comment: to return a single integer value, as OP requested, creating a whole DataSet is a bit overkill don't you think? ExecuteScalar would be a more direct option.

Comment: Yes ExecuteScaler will be best for storing single value. But i shared the detail which i know. I am also a beginner. But thanks for your reply, next time i will try to solve the issue in proper way.

Comment: You know you can edit your answer, right? So you don't need to wait for next time in order to suggest the best solution :-)